# What native resolution should I use for @2x and @3x assets?

Tags: ios

I'm a bit confused here. I'm designing some assets for an application and the devices I'm targeting use @2x and @3x scale assets. However, phones with different resolutions all use @3x assets according to Apple.

iPhone 12 Pro 6.7″  1284 x 2778
iPhone 12 Pro 6.1″  1170 x 2532
iPhone 12 6.1″  1170 x 2532
iPhone 12 5.4″  1080 x 2340
iPhone 11 Pro Max   1242 x 2688
iPhone 11 Pro   1125 x 2436
iPhone XS Max   1242 x 2688
iPhone X, XS    1125 x 2436

So let's say I want to design a background image that takes up the entire screen. What resolution should my @3x image be? If I design it at iPhone X native resolution, will iOS scale it up for something like 12 Pro 6.7? Should I make the native resolution that of 12 Pro 6.7 and let iOS scale it down to XS?

So yeah, what should @3x resolution given all these different native resolutions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Don't overthink this! Ignore your list of phones and think only about *images*. Let's say you have a 100x100 image. That is a point size - that is, you want it to display as 100x100. Then you need three versions:

- 1x - 100x100 pixels
- 2x - 200x200 pixels
- 3x - 300x300 pixels

Stick those into the correct slots in the asset catalog and you are good to go. That's all you need to know!

Why does this work? It's because (1) the runtime will look for the correct version depending on the screen resolution of the device we happen to be running on, and (2) the resulting UIImage will be tagged with the correct `scale` so that the right transform is performed between pixels and points. For example, on a 3x resolution device, the 300x300 version of the image is used, but the UIImage is tagged as having `scale` 3, so this image will be seen as measuring 100x100 points and your code / layout continues to work regardless.